# Can somebody shorten this code?

Tags: c#-3.0

I just finished creating a program (I am a beginner at this programming stuff) Now I might be doing this the total wrong way or my logic might not be the greatest at programming but any help would be amazing I will post my code so far below

This code is used when a button is clicked, the button will send a text then the textbox will get the text.

```
        if (txt1.Text == "")
        {
            txt1.Text = "J";
            btn1.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (txt1.Text != "")
        {
            if (txt2.Text == "")
            {
                txt2.Text = "J";
                btn1.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (txt2.Text != "")
            {
                if (txt3.Text == "")
                {
                    txt3.Text = "J";
                    btn1.Visible = false;
                }
                else if (txt3.Text != "")
                {
                    if (txt4.Text == "")
                    {
                        txt4.Text = "J";
                        btn1.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else if (txt4.Text != "")
                    {
                        if (txt5.Text == "")
                        {
                            txt5.Text = "J";
                            btn1.Visible = false;
                        }
                        else if (txt5.Text != "")
                        {
                            if (txt6.Text == "")
                            {
                                txt6.Text = "J";
                                btn1.Visible = false;
                            }
                            else if (txt6.Text != "")
                            {
                                if (txt7.Text == "")
                                {
                                    txt7.Text = "J";
                                    btn1.Visible = false;
                                }
                                else if (txt7.Text != "")
                                {
                                    if (txt8.Text == "")
                                    {
                                        txt8.Text = "J";
                                        btn1.Visible = false;
                                    }
                                    else if (txt8.Text != "")
                                    {

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all of these text cases into an array for the following loop to work (I have called the array 'txt' here). Based on what you have written this loop should do the same thing as your code but I'm not sure if that's what you really want to do. Your code is setting a single text box to "J" and then hiding your button only if every preceding text field is not an empty string (This will include any of the fields set to null, for example). The conditional then exits.

```
       `for (int i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++) {
            if(txt[i] != "") {
                continue;
            }
            else if(txt[i] == "") {
                txt[i] = "J";
                btn1.Visible = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks man!!! really appreciate what you did. There's just a little problem in your code:

for (int i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++) 
{
            if(txt[i] != "")  // I edited this one to become txt[i].Text
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if(txt[i] == "") // also this one
            {
                txt[i] = "J"; // and this
                btn1.Visible = false;
                break;
            }
}
and in the end it work great

Comment: Glad you got it working. My code was not intended to be functional but just a guide. If you're really trying to set those fields every time then you could possibly initialize all of the text fields to "J" and all of the buttons to false.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I don't know whether this works for C# 3 or not (it should). Try it.

First, you should put all of your text fields into an array:

```
TextField[] textFields = { txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6, txt7, txt8, };
```

Then, loop through the text fields to find a text field that has no text in it:

```
foreach (TextField tf in textFields) {
    if (tf.Text == "") {

    }
}
```

After we find it, we want to set its text to "J" and make `btn1` invisible. Since we already found the text field, we don't need to continue the loop anymore, so we `break`:

```
tf.Text = "J";
btn1.Visible = false;
break;
```

If this doesn't work in C# 3, just update to C# 5 or 6 alright?

Comment: Thanks Sweeper. There is just one question in my head right now. What's the difference between "for" and "foreach"?

Comment: Foreach is like a convenient way of looping through an array. Just google it! :) @PlusUltra